# Using sshEnpoint Service connection and ARM Service connection in a single deploy template yml file in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to combine 2 deploy yaml templates into single deploy template. one of the deploy template is using sshEndpoint `serviceconnection sshEndpoint: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'` and other deploy template is using ARM serviceconnection `azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'`. When I combine these 2 deploy templates and run the pipeline then I am getting below error:

> The pipeline is not valid. Job adls_deployment: Step SSH1 input sshEndpoint expects a service connection of type ssh but the provided service connection is of type azurerm. Job adls_deployment: Step CopyFilesOverSSH1 input sshEndpoint expects a service connection of type ssh but the provided service connection is of type azurerm.

Combined deploy template:

```
jobs:
- deployment: deploy_files
  .
  .
  .
  .


  # Copy files over SSH
  - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
    inputs:
      sshEndpoint: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'
      sourceFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/c.../'
      contents: |
        comm***
    displayName: 'Copy common over SSH'
  
  - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
    inputs:
      sshEndpoint: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'
      sourceFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/cc....'
      contents: '**' 
    displayName: 'Copy files over SSH'

  - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
    inputs:
      sshEndpoint: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'
      sourceFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/ccp....'
      contents: '**'   
    displayName: 'Update the file permission'

  
  ##Copy Files to ADLS
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
    displayName: 'Azure CLI to copy files to Azure Blob storage'

  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.serviceconnection }}'
      scriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        Fil....
    displayName: 'Delete files from Azure Blob storage'
```

How to resolve this error when using sshendpoint service connection and ARM service connection in single deploy template yml file.

Comment: you just need to get different names for your service connection: two different parameters (i.e.: parameters.armServiceConnection and parameters.sshServiceConnection)

Comment: Hi lzzy, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas mentioned in the comment, the issue comes from the service connection type is not correct.

You need to first create a ssh type service connection, then use the service connection name as parameters, and then specify the parameter as service connection value.

Share a little trick. Can help you avoid this type of problem in the future. When you type '- task: sometask@version' in the correct place of YML file of the pipeline in DevOps, you will see a 'Settings' button in the upper left, click it and you can set the value through the UI, which can filter the appropriate options for you:

[image]